# How to add time variables?

Tags: plpgsql

I want to sum every song duration and return the outcome (`ret` variable). The problem is that I can't find a way to add time variables. How to achieve that?

```
$$
declare
    ret time;
    listeners record;
    duration record;
    vc varchar;
    listener_id int;
begin
ret:='00:00:00';
    for listeners in select * from listener loop
        if listeners.nick=$1 then
            listener_id :=listeners.id;
            for duration in select song.duration as dur from playlist, song where song.id=playlist.song_id and listeners.id=playlist.listener_id loop
                ret := ret + duration.dur; //how to add time variables?
            end loop;
        end if;
    end loop;
    return ret;
end;
$$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use data type `interval` for time intervals. But you have yet to learn SQL: write a join instead of procedural code implementing a nested loop:

```
SELECT sum(song.dur)
FROM listeners AS l
   JOIN playlist AS p
      ON l.id = p.listener_id
   JOIN song
      ON song.id = p.song_id;
```

I assume that `utwor` and `song` are the same, otherwise your code does not make much sense.